# Tag for OS-agnostic questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

Stack Overflow has a **[language-agnotic](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/language-agnostic/info)** tag, for questions that don't specifically require a answer in any one language.

Do we need a **os-agnostic** tag, for if we don't care which OS the answer is in?
I've created on as stuck it on [this question.](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/525/desktop-publisher-alternatives-to-indesign)

The usecase is slightly different, I'm not certain if it is a good idea.

Comment: The existence of `language-agnostic` on SO is an argument against: l-a is so inconsistently applied that it's useless.

Answer (score 5):

This is something you should specify within the question itself. The tag was tried on Stack Overflow with the best of intentions, but has become little more than a soupy mess today - filtering on that specific tag yields nothing of specific value. Many of those questions have *nothing* else in common but belonging to that tag.

The same would happen here, filtering on [os-agnostic](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/os-agnostic) would yield image editors, CD burners, CAD programs and probably anything written in Java - it doesn't have any real value in taxonomy as far as the site goes.

Now, *the fact that you need a portable solution should definitely be part of your question*, where you indicate just how important that particular constraint actually is. It probably doesn't belong as a tag.

Comment: So we also don't want OS tags?
Since the only thing in common between CD burners, Image burners etc, are that they are for the same OS?

Comment: @Oxinabox No, OS tags have their utility. There are commonalities on how to search for and install software. Sometimes the recommendation is even “use tool X, which is bundled” — that yields answers which are about the OS.